# When can you cancel the identity functor in a natural isomorphism?

Tags: category-theory, functors

Suppose endofunctors $F, G : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ and the identity functor $1$. If we have an isomorphism $F \times 1 \cong G \times 1$, then under what conditions can we get $F \cong G$?

In Set, this seems to be fine so long as $F\emptyset \cong G\emptyset$. For any non empty set $X$, we have $FX \times X \cong GX \times X \Longrightarrow FX \cong GX$. However in other categories this condition doesn't seem to be enough.

Does anyone know some more general conditions on either $\mathbb C$ or $F,G$ that would let us cancel the $1$ like this?

Comment: I hope the isomorphism $FX\times X \cong GX\times X$ is natural in $X$!

Comment: It sure would be, in the example it would be the component of the natural iso $F \times 1 \to G \times 1$.

Comment: (1) Do you want the isomorphism $FX ≅ GX$ to be natural in $X$? It's not clear because $F≅G$ would mean that but it seems to be contradicted by the second paragraph. (2) Do you have interesting examples of such cancellations, or counter-examples?

Answer (score 0):

If $\mathbf C =\mathbf {Set}$, I'd say that you can cancel the identity as long as $F,G$ preserve copowers. In fact, denoting the singleton by $*$, $$F(*)\times *\cong G(*)\times *$$ implies that $F(*)\cong G(*)$; since every set is a copower of $*$, any functor that preserves copowers is uniquely determined (modulo equivalence) by its image on $*$.

In your question, you probably meant to construct the isomorphisms $FX\cong GX$ restricting $FX\times X\cong GX\times X$ to $FX\times x\cong GX\times x$, choosing $x\in X$ (for any $X$ that is nonempty). However at that point the naturality square, for $f:X\to Y$, is: $\require{AMScd}$ $$\begin{CD}
FX\times x @>\sim>> GX\times x\\
 @VVFfV @VVGfV \\
FY\times y@>\sim>> GY\times y
\end{CD}$$ that if $f(x)\neq y$ is not necessarily commutative.

EDIT. Actually, an isomorphism $\alpha:FX\times X\cong GX\times X$ induces an isomorphism $FX\times x\cong GX\times x$ just if one assumes that this diagram commutes: $$\begin{CD}
FX\times X @>\alpha>> GX\times X\\
 @VVV @VVV \\
X@>\operatorname{id}>> X
\end{CD}$$

Comment: It's possible that Jack Stodart didn't mean that the isomorphism $FX ≅ GX$ is natural in $X$ in the second paragraph.

Comment: @Dabouliplop in the first paragraph he asked about getting an iso $F\cong G$ of functors, so the isos $FX\cong GX$ should be natural in $X$ to make sense.

Comment: Yes, I was speaking specifically of the second paragraph. Moreover we don't have $A×X≅B×X ⇒ A≅B$ for $X$ infinite, so I don't understand this second paragraph of the question. I don't really know any example of this situation. I tried to do with a functor $F:\mathbf{Set}→\mathbf{Set}$ which is not constant to $1$, but with $F(n)=1$ for all $n$ finite. It didn't even produce an example...

Comment: Take $F(X)$ to be $1$ ("undefined") plus the infinite and cofinite parts of $X$, functoriality is given by the direct image or "undefined". Or take $F(X) = βX/X$, the Stone Chech compactification with all standard points identified. Anyway, I can't get any interesting example so I can't even say the statement of the second paragraph of the question is false if we include naturality. (Can we have $F(X)×X ≅ X$ naturally but $F ≠ \operatorname{Id}$?)